# How to choose the platform for my Mobile App and how to evolve it into multiple platform?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm finishing my Masters Degree in Computer Science and i just had this idea for a Mobile App to solve a problem i've been having for the last year or so. I have good knowledge of Java and i know that it's a good language for Android programming, but the thing is that this App would be to target both Android and iOS users.

Considering this, how do mobile developers go about this problem? Is it possible to make the application viable for both platforms or usually it works as a separate application with the same funcionalities?

For either cases, what tools/programming languages would you recommend for me to develop my idea? I'm on my 4th of 5 years but we still had no contact with mobile development.

Any other sugestions you think i might need to take into consideration when starting to develop an app are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java can't be used for cross-platform development, as of my knowledge, but here are some great choices out there for cross-platform development. Here are some:

- [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) - developed by Google (my personal favourite)
- [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)
- [React Native](https://react-native.org/)
- [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin)

The question is does a cross platform SDK suite your needs. If you need to interact a lot with native APIs then it certainly isn't for you and you'll have to build two separate apps.

Another downside to using cross-platform tools is usually app size (for Flutter around 3-5MB larger for a simple app).

Here is my take on why I prefer flutter:

1. It's easy to build nice material UIs, since Google includes many material widgets
2. There are a lot of plugins available at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev)
3. It has close to native performance, because in opposition to the other SDKs the dart code is compiled into native code.

Hope I helped! Good luck in the strange world of app development!